# pygtk combobox focus signal handling

Tags: python, combobox, focus, pygtk, signals

I've been trying to find a way to handle focusing on a pygtk combobox.  The goal is to change the color of the combobox when it is focused and then change it back when focus leaves the combobox.  I've tried using the "focus_out_event" but this doesn't seem to work with combobox.  I've searched extensively for an answer to this problem and it seems this may be a gtk+ bug??

The solution I've come up with so far...

I have 4 separate combobox's cb0 - cb3. I have connected them to the same method...

```
self.cb0.connect("focus", self.focus)
```

In the method I change the state and color...

```
def focus(self, widget, direction):
    if widget.get_state() == gtk.STATE_NORMAL:
        widget.set_state(gtk.STATE_SELECTED)
        widget.modify_base(gtk.STATE_SELECTED, gtk.gdk.Color("#99CCFF"))
    else:
        widget.set_state(gtk.STATE_NORMAL)
        widget.modify_base(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.Color("#FFFFFF"))
```

This provides the desired effect when tabbing with the keyboard. But if the combo boxes are clicked with the mouse I get undesirable results.  Now I'm looking for a way to track mouse clicks.

I can't seem to find a signal or method to check when a specific combo box is clicked.  Using the "grab_notify" signal will fire off a signal for all 4 combo boxes (thus changing all the boxes base color at once.)

This has been a frustrating problem taking waaay too much of my time.  Seems like there should be a simple solution.

Comment: My advice: Changing color of a builtin widget regardless of user's theme/style, probably is not a good idea.

Comment: agreed, but gtk's highlighting of comboBoxes is hard to see.  I mostly just want a way to enhance things, make it more obvious where the focus is.  I'd be happy with a dotted line framing the text portion of the box.